# is it normal that there are a lot of zfs related kernel threads in ubuntu trusty

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I have tow native zfs pools  of a 2T harddisk of mirror 1 on my home desktop pc. But there are 658 kernel threads of  z_fr_iss1,z_ioctl_iss z_ioctl_int z_zvol z_iput z_rd_int z_null_iss z_null_int z_cl_int z_cl_iss  and etc.
I want to know whether it is normal in zfs file system.

```
$ lsmod |grep zfs
zfs                  2692910  5 
zunicode              331170  1 zfs
zcommon                55411  1 zfs
znvpair                89170  2 zfs,zcommon
spl                    96165  3 zfs,zcommon,znvpair
zavl                   15236  1 zfs

$ ps -Af |grep z_|wc
    658    5266   40009
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is normal.  Every system I have set up using ZFS appears like this.

Answer (score 0):

That seems high.

```
lsmod |grep zfs
zfs                  3821568  23
zunicode              348160  1 zfs
zzstd                 487424  1 zfs
zlua                  163840  1 zfs
zavl                   20480  1 zfs
icp                   323584  1 zfs
zcommon               106496  2 zfs,icp
znvpair                98304  2 zfs,zcommon
spl                   122880  6 zfs,icp,zzstd,znvpair,zcommon,zavl

ps -Af |grep z_|wc
61     490    3962
```

This is on a 3-way mirror for rpool, and a single drive partition for bpool, on Zorin Core 16.2r-1.